# Pod from github not working

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods, podspec

I forked [CBZSplashView](https://github.com/rvirin/CBZSplashView) and I'd like to use it in my own project.

To be sure that the problem doesn't come from me, I create a Xcode project from scratch.

My project Podfile  contains one  line :

```
pod 'CBZSplashView', :git=> 'git@github.com:rvirin/CBZSplashView.git',  :branch => 'remy'
```

When I run `pod install` or `pod update` I've got the original version of the pod - not my fork.

What I'm doing wrong?

The `:git` parameter [overrides the source of the podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2317#issuecomment-51718011).

I tried to modify the podspec to indicate that the source files are now on my repository, but didn't work either.

Log of `pod update --verbose`:

```
-> Pre-downloading: `CBZSplashView` from `git@github.com:rvirin/CBZSplashView.git`, tag `1.0.1`
 > GitHub download
   $ /usr/bin/git config core.bare
   true
   $ /usr/bin/git config core.bare
   true
 > Updating cache git repo (/Users/rvi/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/8520768890e6fa2ea91b3d9e8bb9f2afbb31ab60)
     $ /usr/bin/git remote update
     Fetching origin
 > Cloning to Pods folder
     $ /usr/bin/git clone /Users/rvi/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/8520768890e6fa2ea91b3d9e8bb9f2afbb31ab60 /Users/rvi/Devs/Lima/iOS/Lima/Pods/CBZSplashView
     Cloning into '/Users/rvi/Devs/Lima/iOS/Lima/Pods/CBZSplashView'...
     done.
   $ /usr/bin/git fetch origin tags/1.0.1 2>&1
   From /Users/rvi/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/8520768890e6fa2ea91b3d9e8bb9f2afbb31ab60
    * tag               1.0.1      -> FETCH_HEAD
   $ /usr/bin/git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
   HEAD is now at 56d4dc7 change branch
   $ /usr/bin/git checkout -b activated-pod-commit 2>&1
   Switched to a new branch 'activated-pod-commit'
```

Any help is appreciate :)

```
$ pod --version
0.33.1
```

Comment: Can you try this without the `:branch` specification to see if it pulls the master branch of your fork?

Comment: Hi @KeithSmiley, thanks  for your help.
I tried and it didn't worked. so I tried branch, commit, tag, nothing worked ! Moreover, in the log of the pod update, everything appears to work well. See the updated of my question. If you have any thought feel free to tell, this is really strange.

Comment: Hi @RémyVirin, did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Hi @Taz, I think you need to clear your Podfile.lock. Do you still have the same problem ?

Comment: Managed to solve it using tags. The issue with mine seemed to be the fact that I was using a local podspec with the :podspec option. Apparently, using this and the branch option doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't see any [`remy` branch](https://github.com/rvi/CBZSplashView/tree/remy) nor a [`1.0.1` tag](https://github.com/rvi/CBZSplashView/tree/1.0.1) in your repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to install Github repository to use as CocoaPods and paste this in your Podfile :

```
 pod 'CBZSplashView', :git => 'https://github.com/rvi/CBZSplashView.git', :branch => 'master'
```